# Lightest woods that would be strong & stable for 2 components of DIY Wall Stall bar?

Tags: wood-selection, strength, durability, moisture

Lightest woods that would be strong & stable for components of DIY Wall Stall bar?

**Maybe this list can help you help me in shortlisting.**

> Reference list of possible woods available but may not be complete/
>   comprehensive:  :
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_timber_trees

I am guessing both of these could be made of different wood, each with different strength/ hardness/ flex/ weight.

- **Wooden parallel bars/ rods/ dowels**

  - Are less thick than the frame & probably need greater strength, rigidity & less flex
- **The Frame** holding them

  - Made of thicker, wider & bigger pieces of wood, adding more to the weight, so a lighter wood would be better
  - Can this be made from plywood?

**Which woods would you recommend for 2 components as a good/ best possible combination?**

Dimensions & Location:

- Typical standard width is - 34" - Just the space I have now.
- If there's no negative impact, I may consider going upto 38".
- Indian City that tends to be humid & tropical - If its a factor let me know & I can post more details.

**Additional Context: Why am I asking for the lighter wood combination?**

> **These will be removable / mountable from the wall, so lighter is better.**
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeImprovement/comments/3vwbg4/question_hardware_mechanisms_to_make_it_quick/
>
> 3 mounting alternatives gathered from Reddit discussion:
>
> - French Cleats
> - Split Batten
> - Piranha Lox - Mounting System

Sample Stall bar:

[image]

Comment: I might need to remove/ unmount this on a daily basis due to a very small room in apartment. I found the good mounting mechanisms. Don't ask why.. its being removed. Hence, the lighter it is the better without trading off decent the needed strength/ durability.

Comment: You could get super fancy with a hinge on the wall and some pullies to fold it up to the ceiling. Or build another piece of furniture that fits around it!

Comment: ha ha! I wish :) it belongs to family so I have restrictions :)

Comment: One wheel on the bottom corner would make it very easy to roll away, once you've removed it. And just to echo, the advice you've gotten below is sound: any old wood will be fine... you might be over-thinking this one.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the verticals out of run of the mill fir construction lumber, 2x2s or 2x4s, or 4x4s, (or whatever if metric, sorry!) and buy some thick dowels, maybe 2", for the horizontals, whatever's in the hardware store dowel rack (or order online). A 2x6 for that back piece on the wall. I wouldn't over think it. You'll be able to hold an elephant up with it regardless. I wouldn't worry about the weight either, the differences between different woods will be virtually negligible compared to what typical wall mount strategies support.

If fir is not available, just use whatever typical construction wood is available locally. Anything, really. Every wood in your list from the comments is more than sufficient. The differences in density will amount to just a few lbs/kgs range with the small amount of wood you are using.

If you do want to get your overengineering on, though, check out http://www.wood-database.com. You can compare densities, bending strengths, and stabilities of woods there. Your requirements are pretty low, so I would just stick to wood that is readily available in your area instead of finding and ordering more exotic woods (unless you are going for aesthetics or conversation topics).

Comment: I might need to remove/ unmount this on a daily basis due to a very small room in apartment. I found the good mounting mechanisms. Dont ask why.. its being removed. Hence, the lighter it is the better without trading off decent the needed strength/ durability.

Comment: @Alex With the amount of wood you are using the whole thing will be similarly light/heavy no matter what you use, unless you're going for unusually dense woods. If you're going to move it around a lot maybe you can also come up with a plan to stick retractable or out-of-the-way wheels on the bottom and handles on the side, so you can roll it around like a dollie.

Comment: @Alex A lightweight option too, if acceptable, and if you have the tools to machine it, could be extruded aluminum C or square bars for the verticals. Fir does meet all your requirements nicely, though. Strong, affordable, stable, easy to machine, and reasonably light. A good balance of those qualities. That's why it's one of the woods of choice for building houses.

Comment: Maybe this list can help you help me in shortlisting : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_timber_trees 

This would be for family home in Asia.

Comment: When I am back in the states and can walk to local Home Depot/ Lowes I'll use what they have easy. But for this one in India, if you or someone can recommend something from the list or the minimum strength/ hardness rating for the 2 components that would help a newbie like me.

Comment: @Alex I recommend whatever the most readily available typical construction wood is. Even the lowest minimum strength and hardness rating is orders of magnitude above what you need for this. Just use whatever is available locally. Just use anything, really. Every wood in that list is more than sufficient. The differences in density will amount to just a few lbs range with the small amount of wood you are using. Stop over thinking, and just find some wood that looks nice.

Comment: Agreed, construction "white wood" from the lumberyard ought to do the job.

Comment: @JasonC - Maybe I am over thinking it. I'll ask some local folks who I think could help share insight on local timber as well. PS: I know someone who does alumnium work. Would it be strong enough for the frame.. and light as well?

Comment: @Alex Its light and strong but very flexible, you would need a decent sized C or hollow tube for stiffness if you went that route.

Comment: 1/4" wall, [extruded aluminum tube 2x6s](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87834/what-kind-of-extruded-aluminum-sections-to-replace-main-wooden-frame-on-this-diy/87840#87840) weigh more than their lumber equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making the structural parts of the construction out of oak because it is strong and durable and holds fittings well.

The round bars I would make from ash. Ash is a straight, flexible and resilient wood. Things like hammer handles and poles are made from ash.

Comment: I think this is misleading, as for this application generally any type of wood meets the requirements. Not over thinking it is better long term advice. That said I bet bamboo or rattan would make for interesting cross pieces too.

Comment: @ASTPace Oak is in the list. Ash is a common tree in India. The only reason it is not in the cited list is because that is a list of TIMBER trees used for building construction. Ash is a very widely used wood in India for poles and handles.

Comment: You might want to remove your response.  I have removed my erroneous comment